# ¿Cómo regresar a una página después de haber actualizado un formulario?

Tags: php

Tengo una página donde muestra un formulario, que debo seleccionar una opción para poder ver los eventos que tiene un usuario, selecciono alguno y al darle click a un botón "aceptar", me muestra los eventos correspondientes al usuario, dentro de un calendario.js, al darle click a un evento dentro del calendario, me envía a una página nueva para visualizar detalles del evento, allí tengo la opción de regresar y actualizar, el botón regresar si hace bien la función de regresar a la página anterior con los datos que ya había consultado, es decir, con el calendario y los eventos correspondientes del usuario, al darle actualizar, si actualiza, pero me regresa a la página principal, donde debo seleccionar otra vez al usuario para ver sus eventos. Lo que quiero que haga es que al darle "actualizar", haga lo mismo que el botón "regresar", pero obvio ya con la información actualizada...

El botón de regresar tiene esta instrucción:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="regresar" VALUE="Regresar" onclick="window.location.href=\'agenda.php?Regreso=1&Lsasesor='.$LrsqryS->Fields('rasesor').'&Lstipo='.$_REQUEST["Lstipo"].'&Lsestatus='.$_REQUEST["Lsestatus"].'&Lsperfil='.$_REQUEST["Lsperfil"].'&Lsprioridad='.$_REQUEST["Lsprioridad"].'&Lsani='.$_REQUEST["Lsani"].'&Lsmes='.$_REQUEST["Lsmes"].'\'"> ';
```

Intenté poner esa URL en la función que ocupo para actualizar:

```
function actualizar(){.......
if (!$LrsqryU) {
            die ('error en la base de datos');
        } else {
            respaldo();
            echo optMensaje ("Datos actualizados exitosamente");
        echo '<script>window.location.href=AQUÍ ES DONDE PUSE LA URL QUE TIENE EL BOTNÓN DE REGRESAR</script>';
}
```

pero NO regresa a la página con los eventos... Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionar esto o a darme alguna idea...

Comment: Agrega el código del botón  actualizar

Comment: <INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="actualizar" VALUE="Actualizar" '.$statusDis.'>';

Comment: Ese es el botón para actualizar, utiliza la función actualizar(), y normalmente la función me regresa a esta URL:

Comment: if (!$LrsqryU) {
   die ('error en la base de datos');
  } else {
   respaldo();
   echo optMensaje ("Datos actualizados exitosamente");
  echo '<script>window.location.href=\'agenda.php\'</script>';

Comment: Al presionar submit se hace una petición nueva al servidor(a la dirección especificada en el atributo ACTION de form). En $_REQUEST solo se conservan los valores enviados por el nuevo formulario. Estas seguro de que los valores usados para construir la url están presentes en  la nueva petición? De lo contrario se imprimirán cadenas vacías

Comment: No, no estoy seguro que los valores se conserven en la nueva petición. Lo que quiero hacer es eso, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, ¿me puedes ayudar con algunas ideas? por favor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que los datos no se pierden con el botón regresar es porque la redireccion se hace desde esa misma pagina. Mientras que actualizar carga otra pagina en la que solo se conservan los datos enviados por el formulario,desde la cual se hace la redireccion a una url con las variables posiblemente vacías.

Para asegurarte de que se conserven los datos del usuario podrías incluir todos sus datos en etiquetas hidden:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="valor">
```

y así asegurarte de que las variables del usuario se conserven después de enviar el formulario.

Pero PHP te permite hacer manejo de sesiones, que es mas simple y lo que te recomiendo, ya que los datos de sesión se conservan mientras dure y no tienes que preocuparte por enviarlos cada vez.

Para usar sesiones en un archivo php debes usar :

```
session_start();
```

Lo que te da acceso a todas las variables declaradas en $_SESSION

Para agregar una variable a sesion la declaras:

```
$_SESSION["mivariable"]="valordevariable";
```

En tu caso, debes guardar todas las variables del usuario que vayas quieras reusar en otras peticiones al servidor, y sustituir $_REQUEST por $_SESSION para obtener las variables de sesión en lugar de las del formulario

Una vez que terminaste de usar los datos de sesion, los borras con :

```
unset($_SESSION)
```

Aqui un ejemplo directo de la documentacion de php:

[ejemplo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ya tengo avance, utilicé las etiquetas <input type="hidden"> para guardar las variables y si actualiza exitosamente, pero no guarda todas las variables, sólo la del asesor o usuario, falta validar los demás filtros, pero creo que con esta ayuda puedo resolver lo que sigue. ¡Gracias!